# Set target mail address in Firebase Invites

Tags: android, email, firebase, firebase-invites

I am planning to use Firebase invites in order for my app users to reach out (and invite to my app) persons that he/she has added to his administration within the app.

I already have the mail addresses of these targeted persons, so I would like to be able to use this information in setting up the app invite. At this moment this does not seem possible. My current code:

```
Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder( "Please join me to manage " + event ).build();
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INVITE_MANAGER);
```

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder( "Please join me to manage " + event )
.setMailto( "test@test.test" ).build();
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INVITE_MANAGER);
```

Or:

```
intent.putExtra( "EMAIL_TO", "test@test.test");
```

At this moment, the user will have to manually select the user from his contacts (even though the target mail is already known from the context where the user clicks the "invite" action).

Will this be possible in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that's currently available in Firebase Invites. That said, I'll submit a feature request to the team and will update this bug in the future should this ability ever become available.

Thanks for the suggestion!